# Attempt to sorting an array with custom objects return "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: swift2

With Swift 2, I have custom objects in an array that I want to sort.

Here's my custom data type:

```
class Person {
     let birthdate: NSDate
     // class has all of the necessary constructors
}

let people = [Person(date1), Person(date2), ...] // lots of these

// Now attempt to sort them
var sorted = Array(people).sort {$0 < $1}
```

The above will generate this error:

```
 Cannot invoke 'sorted' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> _)'
```

But since the value I want to sort by is NSDate type, I want to use NSDate's `compare` method.

```
var sorted = Array(people).sorted {$0.birthday.compare($1.birthday) == .OrderedAscending}
```

will produce:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

So how can I sort with custom data types in an Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace it with `var sorted = Array(people).sort() {($0 as Person).birthdate) < ($1 as Person).birthdate}`. Apparently you need to specify the type.